# dhcrelay append option 66 and 67

Tags: dhcp, pxe-boot, dhcp-option, bootp

I'm running a PXE Linux server in a VLAN.

How is it possible to use `[dhcrelay][1]` to forward the DHCP requests to the main DHCP server and add the options for PXE with `dhcrelay`?

I've tried something like that:

```
dhcrelay -d -i eth0 10.0.0.42 -a -m append option 66 10.0.0.23
```

Assuming *10.0.0.42* is the DHCP and *10.0.0.23* is the PXE server. But I get these results:

```
Adding 9-byte relay agent option
Forwarded BOOTREQUEST for 00:23:23:23:23:23 to 10.0.0.42
send_packet: Invalid argument
```

Any Ideas about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use dnsmasq in proxyDHCP mode.

This helped me a lot:
https://wiki.fogproject.org/wiki/index.php?title=ProxyDHCP_with_dnsmasq

Answer (score 0):

The DHCP relay does not add the PXE options, the PXE Server does it.